# WebClient.DownloadFile method throws Attempted to read or write protected memory. Exception

Tags: c#, webclient

WebClient.DownloadFile() method throws an exception randomly on few systems
The exception says Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Here is the code:

```
WebClient objWebClient = new WebClient();
string strTargetPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPDATA"), strTempDownloadFolder), "Lib");
if (!Directory.Exists(strTargetPath))
{
     Directory.CreateDirectory(strTargetPath);
}
strzipFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(strTargetPath, "abc.zip");
objWebClient.DownloadFile("some file url", strzipFilePath );
```

What is the reason and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is it a windows application or web application?

Comment: It is a WPF windows application

Comment: If this method is called asynchronously, ensure whether the async thread is handled and disposed properly.

Answer (score 0):

[WebClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient) instance can be disposed with `objWebClient.Dispose()` method. This releases the resources held by the instance.

Alternatively, you can code like this.

```
using (WebClient objWebClient = new WebClient()) {
    objWebClient.DownloadFile(strFileUrl, strzipFilePath);
}
```